# find similar elements in a matrix line in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of which 1 row looks like

```
  [1] 3.630380e-04 2.508100e-04 2.397480e-04 3.583060e-04 1.352502e-03
  [6] 3.615660e-04 1.070212e-04 1.851614e-03 4.862520e-04 3.133680e-05
 [11] 1.509084e-03 1.971120e-04 9.395720e-05 2.467100e-03 3.695440e-05
 [16] 4.840520e-04 9.587220e-05 3.482520e-03 2.580140e-04 4.161880e-03
 [21] 1.826980e-04 3.016000e-03 3.177400e-03 1.281218e-04 8.437420e-04
 [26] 1.823138e-03 9.580200e-04 9.907120e-04 2.582140e-03 2.205160e-04
 [31] 6.575000e-05 1.875756e-03 3.671640e-04 2.528060e-05 4.163980e-04
 [36] 7.939280e-04 2.894380e-04 2.474960e-04 2.101340e-04 2.241000e-03
 [41] 1.254614e-04 5.975560e-04 7.159760e-05 3.125960e-04 1.311358e-03
 [46] 4.742180e-04 7.947780e-07 2.819960e-04 5.153660e-04 4.901420e-04
 [51] 2.108020e-03 1.122480e-03 6.398160e-04 8.454800e-04 3.870840e-05
 [56] 4.835640e-04 1.311954e-03 6.320340e-06 3.058540e-03 5.186800e-04
```

I would like to start in column i (where i would be column 29 for this specific row) and go to the right and the left and detect for how many columns the value stays within 10e-4 of the value of column 29. So I don't want to round any of the numbers but to just evaluate the difference. If the tolerance is kept between col 29 and col 30 and col 29 and col 28 then the algorithm shoudl proceed to check from col 29 to col 27 and col 29 to col 31.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This finds the position of the first values that are outside the tolerance:

```
x <- c(3.630380e-04,2.508100e-04,2.397480e-04,3.583060e-04,1.352502e-03,
3.615660e-04,1.070212e-04,1.851614e-03,4.862520e-04,3.133680e-05,
1.509084e-03,1.971120e-04,9.395720e-05,2.467100e-03,3.695440e-05,
4.840520e-04,9.587220e-05,3.482520e-03,2.580140e-04,4.161880e-03,
1.826980e-04,3.016000e-03,3.177400e-03,1.281218e-04,8.437420e-04,
1.823138e-03,9.580200e-04,9.907120e-04,2.582140e-03,2.205160e-04,
6.575000e-05,1.875756e-03,3.671640e-04,2.528060e-05,4.163980e-04,
7.939280e-04,2.894380e-04,2.474960e-04,2.101340e-04,2.241000e-03,
1.254614e-04,5.975560e-04,7.159760e-05,3.125960e-04,1.311358e-03,
4.742180e-04,7.947780e-07,2.819960e-04,5.153660e-04,4.901420e-04,
2.108020e-03,1.122480e-03,6.398160e-04,8.454800e-04,3.870840e-05,
4.835640e-04,1.311954e-03,6.320340e-06,3.058540e-03,5.186800e-04)

search.fun <- function(x, i, tol) {
  test <- (x - x[i]) > tol
  a <- head(test, i)
  lwr <- if (any(a)) i - which.max(rev(a)) + 1 else -Inf
  b <- tail(test, -i)
  upr <- if (any(b)) i + which.max(b) else Inf
  setNames(c(lwr, upr), c("lwr", "upr"))
  }

search.fun(x, 29, 5e-5)
#lwr upr 
#23  59
```

Here I assume that RAM is not a concern. Also, if the vectors are huge and the expected interval very small, it might be more efficient to use a `for` loop.

Adjust as needed (you don't say what you want to return).

Comment: could you potentially integrate a case what happens when the search is going to hit the last or the first column of the row? so if the value is in the tolerance for all values in the row?

Comment: Moreover, what happens if the value is in the tolerance, than out of the tolerance and then in again? The counting would need to stop the first time it is out of the tolerance.....but you take max..or do i misunderstand?

Comment: Regarding your first comment: This isn't a code generating service. You are expected to do some work yourself. However, I've implemented handling of these cases . Regarding your second comment: Yes, you misunderstand. `which.max` finds the first `TRUE` value. Look at `which.max(c(F, T, F, T))`.

Comment: Hello...okay I understand. can I still ask why you hardcoded the 29 into this line? test <- (x - x[29]) > tol; Because afterwards you write it as i ? As a really last thing do you think it is possible to wrap this in an apply function to do it for several rows of a matrix (mapply?)

Comment: It is really only about making it general usable and not only for the case that the column which is the centre is 29.....

Comment: Well, obviously that was a relict from developing the function. And of course it can be used with `apply`.